# The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

As I created my first app and run, I got this error.

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object

```
const electron = require("electron");

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require(electron);

let createWindow = () => {
  let window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  // load the index.html file
  window.loadFile("index.html");
  
  window.webContents.openDevTools();
};

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

// Quit when all windows closed
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("active", () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require(electron);
```

With the following fix

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
```

This is because `require()` requires a string as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You already `require`d electron, so use it:

```js
const electron = require("electron");

const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
```

If all you need from `electron` is `app` and `BrowserWindow`, simply destructure right from the `require`:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
```