# Sub folders for command handler discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, discord.js

So I have this problem.
I am trying to make use of sub commands in my discord.js bot since I made a few commands already and somehow i cant make my bot read my sub folders at  `./commands/**/*.js`
I am using discord.js version 14.13.0 and glob version of 10.3.4.

here is my index.js file:

```js
    console.clear();
    console.log(" Loading...");
    
    const fs = require('node:fs');
    const path = require('node:path');
    
    const {
        glob,
        globSync,
        globStream,
        globStreamSync,
        Glob
    } = require("glob");    
    
    const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
    const { token } = require("./config.json");
    
    const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
    
    
    client.commands = new Collection();
    
    const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
    const commandFiles = glob.sync(path.join(commandsPath, "**/*.js"));
    
    
    for (const file of commandsPath) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`⛔ [WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" propety!`);
        }
    }
    
    
    const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
    const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    
    for (const file of eventFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
        const event = require(filePath);
        if (event.once) {
            client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
        } else {
            client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
        }
    }
    
    
    client.login(token);
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
node:internal/validators:162
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:3)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/filip/Code/SimpleDCbot/index.js:28:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
 Loading...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/filip/Code/SimpleDCbot/commands/'
Require stack:
- /home/filip/Code/SimpleDCbot/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/filip/Code/SimpleDCbot/index.js:32:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/filip/Code/SimpleDCbot/index.js' ]
}

Node.js v20.5.1
```

Comment: `for (const file of commandsPath) {` maybe `for (const file of commandFiles) {` ?

Comment: For statements of appreciation, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior on chit chat.

Answer (score 0):

```
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = glob.sync(path.join(commandsPath, "**/*.js"));



for (const file of commandsPath) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    if('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`⛔ [WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" propety!`);
    }
}
```

This block seems to cause problems. Notice how you never use `commandfiles` . I think you mean to do it like this:

```
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = glob.sync(path.join(commandsPath, "**/*.js"));


// Loop over commandFiles, not commandsPath, which is a string anyway
for (const file of commandFiles ) {
    // Next line should not be needed, you already use path.join when defining commandFiles
    //const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    // The variable file should now contain the path you need
    const command = require(file);
    if('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        // Here, filePath needs to be switched to file also
        console.log(`⛔ [WARNING] The command at ${file} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property!`);
    }
}
```

Note how your second error says

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/filip/Code/SimpleDCbot/commands/'
```

It is not looking for a command, but for the path which is not a module. This is consistent with the wrong variable in the `for`-loop.

It is probably also necessary to enclose your dynamic file paths with quotes to avoid the first error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array` as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500332/the-id-argument-must-be-of-type-string-received-type-object). It might look like `require("\'" + file + "\'")` or something similar.